# Need help parsing through a website for release dates of albums

Tags: html, powershell, parsing, scripting, compare

I'm new to powershell and like everything new I try, I like to study using something I'm interested in. I'm trying to figure out the pseudocode to a script. I would like to make an automated script that parses through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_years_in_hip_hop_music . and for each year, select each album and compare the current date to the release date of the album and if its a match of Month and Day add it to a list, with artist and album title, then FINALLY email me the list of the days album releases. Not looking for the exact code, but an idea of where to start and steps to take.

```
$album = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blonde_(Frank_Ocean_album)"
$today = Get-Date -Format yyyy-M-dd
$date = $album.AllElements | where tagname -EQ "td" | where class -EQ "published" | select innertext
$date
```

This all I have so far. I started small on one album and returned release date.

Comment: Pretty sure this is an exercise in futility since there is no way to know what links from the pages linked on the Years in Hip Hop page lead to a song, and what leads to other random things. You could reduce links by looking for things that link to `/wiki/<something>`, but even then you'd get links for artists, albums, songs, and random references. You're looking at likely thousands of links for dozens of songs, to find the handful that match a given day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script would be something like:

```
$YIHHM = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_years_in_hip_hop_music'
$SongPages = ForEach($YearLink in ($YIHHM.Links | Where {$_.href -match '/wiki/.*in_hip_hop_music'})){
    $ThisYear = Invoke-WebRequest "https://en.wikipedia.org$($YearLink.href)"
    $ThisYear.Links | Where{$_.href -match '^/wiki/'} | ForEach-Object{
        $Page = Invoke-WebRequest "https://en.wikipedia.org$($_.href)"
        #Check if there's a published class, and if there is output the page
        If($_.tagname -eq 'td' and $_.class -eq 'published'){$Page}
    }
}
```

Then you'd want to filter `$SongPages` for the exact date they were released compared to the current date to see if the Month and Day properties matched. I suppose you could do that in the same loop where you are checking if there is a published class. Then you just have to determine the song. This is still going to take forever though due to the number of links, and the small percentage of them that are going to be a link to a song.